# mysql where clause error in trigger

Tags: mysql

I've added triggers between `user` TABLE and `school` TABLE, for student-transferring school and student-adding in school, the `numbers_of_school` field is where problem lies maybe.

The error msg is:

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NEW.NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT < 0;
END' at line 4**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `school` (
  `school_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `school_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `master` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `numbers_of_student` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`school_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- TABLE `school`
--
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `tg_school_insert`; 
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `tg_school_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `school`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT = NULL THEN
        SET NEW.NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT = 0;
    END IF;
END
//
DELIMITER ;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `tg_school_delete`; 
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `tg_school_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `school`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DELETE FROM DEPARTMENT
WHERE SCHOOL_ID=OLD.SCHOOL_ID;
UPDATE USER
SET SCHOOL_ID = NULL
WHERE SCHOOL_ID = OLD.SCHOOL_ID;
END
//
DELIMITER ;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `tg_school_update`; 
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `tg_school_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `school`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET NEW.NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT = 0
WHERE NEW.NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT < 0;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

and my `user` table below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `department_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `school_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `realname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `familyname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthdate` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `photo` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `school_enteryear` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `activestat` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `onlinestat` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `regtime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `avatar` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `desc` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `self_comment` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uk_email` (`email`),
  KEY `fk_user_department_id_idx` (`department_id`),
  KEY `fk_user_school_id_idx` (`school_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- TRIGGER `user`
--
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `tg_user_delete`; 
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `tg_user_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `user`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DELETE FROM HOBBY WHERE USER_ID = OLD.USER_ID;
DELETE FROM USER_ALBUM_PHOTO WHERE USER_ID = OLD.USER_ID;
DELETE FROM USER_DIARY WHERE USER_ID = OLD.USER_ID;
DELETE FROM USER_MSG WHERE FROM_ID = OLD.USER_ID OR TO_ID = OLD.USER_ID;
DELETE FROM USER_NOTIFICATION WHERE USER_ID = OLD.USER_ID;
DELETE FROM USER_OP WHERE USER_ID = OLD.USER_ID;
DELETE FROM USER_FEED WHERE USER_ID = OLD.USER_ID;
DELETE FROM USER_RELATION WHERE USER_ID = OLD.USER_ID OR USER2_ID = OLD.USER_ID;
DELETE FROM USER_SPECIAL WHERE USER_ID = OLD.USER_ID;
DELETE FROM USER_STATUS WHERE USER_ID = OLD.USER_ID;
DELETE FROM USER_DIARY_COMMENT WHERE USER_ID = OLD.USER_ID;
DELETE FROM USER_STATUS_COMMENT WHERE USER_ID = OLD.USER_ID;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `tg_user_bf_insert`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `tg_user_bf_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `user`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.regtime = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN
        SET NEW.regtime = NOW();
    END IF;
END
//
DELIMITER ;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `tg_user_insert`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `tg_user_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `user`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE SCHOOL SET NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT=NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT+1
WHERE SCHOOL_ID = NEW.SCHOOL_ID;
INSERT INTO HOBBY(`user_id`) VALUES(NEW.USER_ID);
END
//
DELIMITER ;


DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `tg_user_update_school`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `tg_user_update_school` AFTER UPDATE ON `user`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE SCHOOL
SET NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT=NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT-1
WHERE OLD.SCHOOL_ID <> NEW.SCHOOL_ID AND SCHOOL_ID = OLD.SCHOOL_ID;
UPDATE SCHOOL
SET NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT=NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT+1
WHERE OLD.SCHOOL_ID <> NEW.SCHOOL_ID AND SCHOOL_ID = NEW.SCHOOL_ID;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

But where is the syntax error?
thank you!

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting? Errors say alot more info than just bugging us ;)

Comment: more info? Sorry, but I don't exactly get your meanings. @bonCodigo

Comment: @bonCodigo The error message is the big bold bit of text at the top of the question ;)

Comment: @Clive thx, before you answered I suspected that if there would be more error info that I didn't notice.

Comment: @bonCodigo Sorry, I don't really get in. you mean the sentence in the trigger above the `tg_update_school`?

Comment: Yup saw the error :D well ignore that comment. Can your number of students be minus?

Comment: @bonCodigo I've tried it, didn't work :(

Comment: @bonCodigo I didn't set constraints on the data structure of `numbers_of_student` but I want to use trigger to limit it not being minus, so the update trigger is there.

Comment: I would just use a case : you could try. `SET NEW.NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT = 
    ( CASE
         WHEN NEW.NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT  < 0 THEN 0
         NEW.NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT 
       END
    )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this as an answer because it is too long for a comment. I just ran all of your scripts and the error is with this piece of code:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `tg_school_update`; 
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `tg_school_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `school`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET NEW.NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT = 0
WHERE NEW.NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT < 0;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

It doesn't like the line:

```
WHERE NEW.NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT < 0;
```

If you remove this the trigger is created.  So my question is, is it possible to negative number of students?

Or change the code to:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `tg_school_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `school`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET NEW.NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT = case when NEW.NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT < 0 then 0 else NEW.NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT end;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: thanks for answer. I think It is possible to negative number of students for the trigger in `user` table can set substract the number of students when a student is seemed as transferring.

Comment: @Bluefeet I suspected the same, but OP said he is just preventing from having a negative number ... :$

Comment: @SummerR.L see my edit, I got it to create the trigger with the `case`

Comment: all right, I think you're right. Oh my. when a school is with 0 number of students, no student can transferred to other school from it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment: Try this out instead of the current code you use.

```
SET NEW.NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT = 
( CASE WHEN NEW.NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT < 0 THEN 0 
  ELSE NEW.NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT 
END )
```

Comment: So, may I know why where clause failed? the difference between where clause and when clause with case? :)

Comment: @SummerR.L my answer has `case` too :( why only mine got outcast?

Comment: Sorry, I just firstly sawed his answer. although your syntax is clearer.

Comment: and I tried it, it didn't work. :( maybe you lost `ELSE` after `THEN 0`.

Comment: @SummerR.L the way you use `where` clause didn't look right. Usually for such validations I depend on `case` so I thought that's what would need here. But I am more than happy to hear the exact great reason :) Yeah preceisely I have lost `else`.

Comment: I think you're right and its my logical thoughts failed not the syntax error in fact. I'll pay attention in the next time.@bonCodigo

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
SET NEW.NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT = 0
WHERE NEW.NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT < 0;
```

To this:

```
SET NEW.NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT 
    = GREATEST(NEW.NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT, 0);
```

You also have a bug. This line:

```
IF NEW.NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT = NULL THEN
```

Should be:

```
IF NEW.NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT IS NULL THEN
```

the comparison of `column = null` is never true - you must use the special `is null` syntax to test for null.

Comment: It's not valid syntax. Even though a human would understand what you coded, WHERE is not expected here in SQL. The code I changed it to expresses your intention in the minimum amount of code.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tg_school_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `school`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   IF NEW.NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT < 0
   THEN SET NEW.NUMBERS_OF_STUDENT = 0;
   END IF;
END;
```

Comment: is it IF clause sth. special? Yesterday, when I added trigger on set regtime = now(); I failed at the very beginning without IF clause also.

Comment: No, there's nothing special about IF, it's just another kind of statement. The problem with `set regtime = now();` is that user variables need to begin with `@`, so it should be `set @regtime = now();`. See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: user variables, you mean the user is protection word so its variables is special? @Barmar

Comment: No, I mean user-defined variables have to begin with `@`. See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html). Names without this prefix are assumed to be table column names.

Comment: but my `regtime` is a column in `user` TABLE in deed. @Barmar

Comment: Then I'm not sure why you got the error, it probably depends on where you put the statement.

Comment: the previous trigger statement is exactly like this:     DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `tg_user_bf_insert`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `tg_user_bf_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `user`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        SET NEW.regtime = NOW();
END
//
DELIMITER ; @Barmar many thanks